# How to install awscli using pip in library/node Docker image

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, pip

I'm trying to install `awscli` using `pip` (as per Amazon's recommendations) in a custom Docker image that comes `FROM library/node:6.11.2`. Here's a repro:

```
FROM library/node:6.11.2

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        python \
        python-pip \
        python-setuptools \
        groff \
        less \
    && pip --no-cache-dir install --upgrade awscli \
    && apt-get clean

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

However, with the above I'm met with:

```
no such option: --no-cache-dir
```

Presumably because I've got incorrect versions of Python and/or Pip?

I'm installing Python, Pip, and awscli in a similar way with `FROM maven:3.5.0-jdk-8` and there it works just fine. I'm unsure what the *relevant* differences between the two images are.

Removing said option from my Dockerfile doesn't do me much good either, because then I'm met with a big pile of different errors, an excerpt here:

```
Installing collected packages: awscli, PyYAML, docutils, rsa, colorama, botocore, s3transfer, pyasn1, jmespath, python-dateutil, futures, six
  Running setup.py install for PyYAML
    checking if libyaml is compilable
### ABBREVIATED ###
    ext/_yaml.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
### ABBREVIATED ###
```

Bottom line: how do you properly install `awscli` in `library/node:6.x` based images?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Adding `python-dev` as per [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46039200/419956) works, but throws an alarming number of compiler warnings (errors?), so I went with a variation of [@SergeyKoralev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46039283/419956), which needed some tweaking before it worked.

Here's the changes I needed to make this work:

1. Change to `python3` and `pip3` everywhere.
2. Add a statement to upgrade `pip` itself.
3. Separate the `awscli` install in a separate `RUN` command.

Here's a full repro that *does* seem to work:

```
FROM library/node:6.11.2

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        python3 \
        python3-pip \
        python3-setuptools \
        groff \
        less \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip \
    && apt-get clean

RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install --upgrade awscli

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

You can probably also keep the `aws` install in the same `RUN` layer if you add a shell command before the install that refreshes things after upgrading pip. Not sure how though.

Comment: Whoever is using this answer now, keep in mind pip3 will not work. Use `python3 -m pip --no-cache-dir install --upgrade awscli` instead. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49836753/6273492

Answer (score 8):

All the answers are about aws-cli version 1, If you want version 2 try the below

```
FROM node:lts-stretch-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        unzip \
        curl \
    && apt-get clean \
    && curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" \
    && unzip awscliv2.zip \
    && ./aws/install \
    && rm -rf \
        awscliv2.zip \
    && apt-get -y purge curl \
    && apt-get -y purge unzip 

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Comment: That's very clear.

Answer (score 5):

As you have correctly stated, `pip` installing on the docker image you are using is an older one not supporting `--no-cache-dir`. You can try updating that or you can also fix the second problem which is about missing python source headers. This can be fixed by installing `python-dev` package. Just add that to the list of packages installed in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM library/node:6.11.2

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        python \
        python-dev \
        python-pip \
        python-setuptools \
        groff \
        less \
    && pip install --upgrade awscli \
    && apt-get clean

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

You can then run `aws` which should be on your path.

Comment: This gives an alarming number (dozens) of warnings (or errors?) though on building the image, aren't those releveant then?

Answer (score 5):

Your image is based on Debian Jessie, so you are installing Python 2.7. Try using Python 3.x:

```
apt-get install -y python3-pip
pip3 install awscli
```

Comment: Thx for the response, but I could not get this to work. Could you show me how my Dockerfile should be updated? I've tried several variations, including replacing "python" with "python3" (and "pip" with "pip3") everywhere in my file but the error persists...

Comment: This builds without any problem: https://pastebin.com/LPPJfgry Are you sure you see error messages? PyYAML will output a lot of compiler code, but Docker will build the image eventually without any errors. I'm using Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87.

Comment: Your pastebin however diverges from  my question as well as your answer though? It contains a `python3-dev` line (that is not in your answer, but it *is* in the *other* answer), and you've removed my `--no-cache-dir` directive. With only the changes you've mentioned in your *answer* (and thus *keeping* that directive which I would like to keep) things won't work. https://pastebin.com/UwyY53Pv

Comment: Thx again for your suggestion though, with some adjustments I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Install AWS CLI in docker container using below command:

```
apt upgrade -y;apt update;apt install python3 python3-pip python3-setuptools -y; python3 -m pip --no-cache-dir install --upgrade awscli
```

To check the assumed role or AWS identity run below command:

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `FROM node:18-alpine`; Update your packages then install the required packages before building you dependencies with:

`RUN apk --no-cache add --virtual builds-deps build-base python3`

I then upgraded pip before installing the AWS CLI

`RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \ pip install --upgrade awscli`.

Here is the fullcode:

```
## Install required packages for awsebcli ##
RUN apk update && apk add --update --no-cache \
    git \
    bash \
    curl \
    openssh \
    python3 \
    py3-pip \
    py-cryptography \
    wget \
    curl

RUN apk --no-cache add --virtual builds-deps build-base python3
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --upgrade awscli
```

Credit goes to [metacollective9](https://github.com/metacollective9/serverless_ci/blob/main/Dockerfile)

Answer (score 0):

```
apk add --no-cache curl jq python3 py3-pip
pip install awscli
```

was working perfect for us until last week, we had :

```
error: externally-managed-environment
× This environment is externally managed
╰─> 
The system-wide python installation should be maintained using the system
package manager (apk) only.

If the package in question is not packaged already (and hence installable via
"apk add py3-somepackage"), please consider installing it inside a virtual
environment
```

the solution proposed, worked perfect :

```
apk add --no-cache curl jq python3 py3-pip
python3 -m venv /path/to/venv
. /path/to/venv/bin/activate
pip install awscli
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an alpine base image, I recommend adding this to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache aws-cli
```

See https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4971#issuecomment-1784175703