# Unable to install Python packages using pip in Ubuntu Linux: InsecurePlatformWarning, SSLError, tlsv1 alert protocol version

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, ssl, pip

Previously I used to install packages by pip but now I am trying to install a Python library using pip, getting an SSL error:

```
 /home/teleduce/.virtualenvs/teleduce_handler/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
 /home/teleduce/.virtualenvs/teleduce_handler/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/xlwt/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version - skipping
```

**OpenSSL and TLS Version**

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
SSLv3
TLSv1.2
```

**Pip version**

```
pip 8.1.2 from /home/teleduce/.virtualenvs/project_name/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

**OS Information**

```
Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-44-generic x86_64)
```

I tried

```
pip install --upgrade pip
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

but it does not work for me. Got an error message is

> SSL routines: SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Can you try updating openssl to a higher version? I don't know if one is available in the canonical repo for your OS so you might have to use a different repo.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1336153/pip-cannot-fetch-url-because-of-an-error-with-the-ssl-certificate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install Python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Answer (score 38):

The SSLError occurs because system OpenSSL library version (the one linked to your Python upon compilation) was below 1.0.1 *the day when Python has been installed* or your current Python version is below 2.7.9 / 3.4, because neither of these really support TLS 1.2 protocol version which the Python Package Index (PyPI) [now requires](https://pyfound.blogspot.com/2017/01/time-to-upgrade-your-python-tls-v12.html) from `pip` to connect.

Distributions usually cannot easily upgrade old openssl and system Python without undergoing a full OS upgrade, which is not always desirable. You could compile your own 'non-system' OpenSSL from recent [sources](https://www.openssl.org/source/) and then try to compile a standalone 'non-system' [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/) linking it against the OpenSSL you have just compiled, but sometimes this approach is also unfeasible due to various limitations.

### Solution

Popular recommendations, such as to pip install requests[secure] or urllib3[secure], often cannot help fix `pip` because pip [itself](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/3411) is [affected](https://pyfound.blogspot.com/2018/03/warehouse-all-new-pypi-is-now-in-beta.html) and won't be able to connect to PyPI to install anything. We cannot ask pip to connect to PyPI to fix pip's inability to connect to PyPI. :) To fix it without upgrading Python, we need to install relevant packages manually, resolving dependencies:

- `PyOpenSSL` and `cryptography` (its `manylinux1` wheel ships newer openssl library);
- their dependencies:  `asn1crypto`, `cffi`, `enum34`, `idna`, `ipaddress`, `pycparser`, `six`;
- any `pip` 10+ version, because older pip versions did not really use cryptography - only the standard library's `ssl` module (you don't require a new pip version if yours is already 10 or above, any pip v10+ will do)

> Tested on ancient Ubuntu with old non-working pip and outdated system openssl version.

### Step 1 - Download

**Download** the following packages from Python Packing Index (pypi.org) *via your web browser of choice* -- choose recent *manylinux1* wheels (**.whl**) for your OS/platform:

> [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/#files), [asn1crypto](https://pypi.org/project/asn1crypto/#files), [enum34](https://pypi.org/project/enum34/#files), [idna](https://pypi.org/project/idna/#files), [six](https://pypi.org/project/six/#files), [ipaddress](https://pypi.org/project/ipaddress/#files), [pyOpenSSL](https://pypi.org/project/pyOpenSSL/#files), [cffi](https://pypi.org/project/cffi/#files), [cryptography](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/#files) wheels; and also [pycparser](https://pypi.org/project/pycparser/#files) (a non-wheel, it will be a tar.gz)

**cp27-** stands for Python 2.7, **cp36-** for Python 3.6;
**mu-** type manylinux wheels are a common choice, as they are for Pythons that store Unicode data in UCS-4 (UTF-32) format -- here's how to check it:
`$ python -c "import sys; print('UCS4/UTF-32: mu-manylinux1' if sys.maxunicode > 65535 else 'UCS2/UTF-16: m-manylinux1')"`

**Note for Python 3**: the `cp34-abi3-manylinux1` cryptography's wheel can be used with **any** Python version>=3.4 because abi3 [support](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/faq/#why-are-there-no-wheels-for-python-3-5-on-linux-or-macos) multiple versions of Python3, e.g *cryptography-2.5-cp34-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.4 MB)*

Basically, **wheels** are ZIP archives with a specially formatted file name and the .whl extension, containing a relocatable Python package. The package can be pure-python, but also can have **pre-compiled** C libraries for python bindings, so it can be installed without the need to have certain system dependencies like gcc, python-dev and other C headers/libs, often required for classic .tar.gz format packages. This also allows to use exact versions of programs bundled within each wheel. The **manylinux1**_{x86_64,i686} wheel platform tag was adopted in [PEP-513](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0513/) and will work on *many* linux systems, including the popular desktop and server distros in common use. Expect *manylinux2* tag in future!

Simply create a new directory, for example:
`$ mkdir ~/wheels_dir`
and copy (or move) all the downloaded packages to that directory.

No other files (except the downloaded wheels) and no subdirs there please!

### Step 2 - Install

If your current `pip` version is below 8.1, the newer pip version has to be installed before proceeding with all other packages:
`$ pip install --user --no-index ~/wheels_dir/pip-19.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl`
It will upgrade pip to handle the new *multilinux1* wheel format and help avoid the *"not a supported wheel on this platform"* error.

To install all the packages at user home level:
`$ pip install --user --no-index ~/wheels_dir/*`
`$ pip3` in Python 3

If installing in a new or existing virtualenv, omit the `--user` option:

```
$ source bin/activate
$ pip install --no-index ~/wheels_dir/*
```

Pip will resolve correct installation order and dependencies automa*g*ically.
(one could also create a requirements.txt for this if so needed)

> *Note:* Unless you install in a Python virtualenv or venv, it is highly recommended to always use `--user` flag with pip. It then deploys python packages under your home dir in ~/.local/lib/ In fact, this option is always *On* by default in distro-patched pip versions provided by `python3-pip` and `python-pip` packages in **recent** versions of popular distros such as Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora, etc. Please try to [avoid](https://askubuntu.com/a/116645) `sudo pip`, as using pip with root access interferes with your OS package manager subsystem (apt, yum, etc) and may [affect](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2379169&p=13719476#post13719476) essential OS components that depend on the distro-supplied system python.

Run `$ pip freeze` (or `pip3 freeze` in Python 3) command to check the results and ensure all packages have been installed for your Python environment.

Congratulations! Now your pip should work with PyPI, and you can try to look up something like `pip search colorama` from the online PyPI repo.

### Verify

You can see the detailed summary of your system SSL/TLS setup by querying the installed `pyOpenSSL` lib directly:
`$ python -m OpenSSL.debug`
(a *ModuleNotFoundError* would mean the pyOpenSSL package was not installed)

Cryptography's linked OpenSSL shared lib doesn't conflict in any way with your system Python's openssl version. It may now be a good opportunity to also update your collection of root SSL certificates for the future by installing the latest python `certifi` package.

### Why it works

Earlier versions of pip (before 10) only used the standard library's `ssl` module (which is a Python API to system OpenSSL library) without any possible fallback to other libraries like `cryptography`. Since version 10, pip now can use pyOpenSSL with cryptography, if present in the environment.

The `manylinux1` wheel of `cryptography` package **includes** recent OpenSSL library that supports all TLS protocols as high as v1.3 regardless of what's on your platform (PyPI expects pip to support TLSv1.2). That's why this wheel weighs 2.1 Mb -- the archive ships a shared lib binding:

```
$ strings site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.so | grep OpenSSL -m1  
OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018  
$ python -c "from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl import backend as b; print b.openssl_version_text()"  
OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018  
$ python -c "from OpenSSL import SSL; print SSL.SSLeay_version(0)"  
OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018  
$ python -c "import requests; print requests.get('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check').json()['tls_version']"  
TLS 1.3
```

> The Cryptography wheel contains a statically-linked OpenSSL binding, which ensures that you have access to the most-recent OpenSSL releases without corrupting your system dependencies.
> This will allow you to continue to use relatively old Linux distributions (such as LTS releases), while making sure you have the most recent OpenSSL available to your Python programs. (https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/)

In Python 2, the standard library's `ssl` module began supporting PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2 flag explicitly since version 2.7.9, while in Python 3 - since version 3.4; but TLSv1.2 connections would only work **if and only if** the TLSv1.2-capable system-wide OpenSSL library was **already available** in the system by the time Python was being compiled and linked against it. TLSv1.2 requires a minimum of OpenSSL 1.0.1 to function but OpenSSL 1.0.2 (or later) is generally recommended (it uses TLSv1.2 by default).

If you do have Python 2.7.9+ or 3.4+, and its `ssl` module had been, in fact, compiled against system openssl, say v1.0.2k, then even old pip (such as v6.0.8) would *still* be working with PyPI as of the time of this writing, and you would not even need cryptography for that. To check the standard library Python `ssl` and system openssl versions:
`$ python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)" && openssl version`
*OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010*

Even if we upgraded some outdated distro-supplied openssl, or compiled the newest one, we can't just re-link the existing Python installation to it: the `ssl` module was hard-linked to the system-supplied OpenSSL upon compilation/installation of Python, and not vice versa. So, basically, one could not take advantage of new TLS protocols without recompiling/reinstalling Python itself (that should be versions 2.7.9+ / 3.4+ at least) to link it to the new system openssl library. This is where the above `pyopenssl`+`cryptography` approach comes to the rescue.

Happy TLSing! :)

Comment: This worked for me. I did have a warning while installing cryptography, because my version of python `Python 2.7 (r27:82500, Aug 07 2010, 16:54:59)` doesn't support `hmac.compare_digest`. This is on an old OpenSUSE 11.4 system.

Comment: @Brian yeah, since v8.1.0+ pip can silence warnings like this: `$ PYTHONWARNINGS=ignore pip --version` or `$ python -W ignore -m pip --version`

Comment: Other options for `hmac.compare_digest` warning [include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51778764): either cryptography==2.2.2, or Python>2.7.6, or filtering out the [warning itself](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/pull/4261/) in your app code if in use.. @Brian

Comment: WOW. This is one of the most useful, thorough amswers I've ever seen on StackOverflow (and that's saying a lot). Four years after it was posted, the information enabled me to figure out how to update `pip` and `pip3` on an old MacOS system. Now I can install Python modules from PyPI!

Comment: BTW, if you want to expand the answer a bit for MacOS, here's the only non-obvious difference: After installing the new `pip3` shell script, the old one, which came with the OS, is still in the PATH, and it won't work with the new `pip` module (not to be confused with the `pip` shell script). The error message says that it can't import `main`. The new `pip3` shell script gets installed in `~/Library/Python/3.4/bin` (the version number might be different, of course); you must run that instead.

Comment: @Ben Thank you, glad it helped revive another old system. Regarding the `import main` error, yeah, it's common nowadays past manual pip upgrades in most distro OSes, both Linux and Mac. I've covered a range of solutions in a related thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49988228/9575715)

Comment: @AlexC. Thanks - although there are multiple answers to this problem yours was the only one that helped me. My situation was that I did not have `sudo` access and was limited in what I could install. However, during the installation step using `pip3 install --no-index ~/wheels_dir/*` was giving errors for `pycparser` and `cffi`. I had to install these separately `pip3 install --no-index ./wheels_dir/cffi-1.13.0.tar.gz` and `pip3 install --no-index ./wheels_dir/pycparser-2.19.tar.gz` before doing your version with the wildcard. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you very much it worked for me too, wanted to install Django on an old macbook, I had to install some dependancies manually though via installing their tar.gz then unpack and run their "setup.py"

Comment: This is the best answer I've ever seen on StackOverflow