# How to silence EllipticCurvePublicNumbers.encode_point CryptographyDeprecationWarning when using Paramiko in Python

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, deprecation-warning

CryptographyDeprecationWarning:

> encode_point has been deprecated on EllipticCurvePublicNumbers and will be removed in a future version. Please use EllipticCurvePublicKey.public_bytes to obtain both compressed and uncompressed point encoding.

Answer (score 17):

This has been fixed in Paramiko 2.5.0 already:
https://www.paramiko.org/changelog.html#2.5.0
https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/pull/1379
https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1369

Comment: So ```pip3 install --upgrade paramiko``` [is the actionable fix path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58347960/605356), right?

Comment: For Debian Buster, there is an updated package in backports: https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/python-paramiko

Answer (score 8):

I've had better success with:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore", cryptography.utils.CryptographyDeprecationWarning)
```

Comment: If you have `DeprecatedIn23` then you must have `cryptography<=2.4.2`, because the symbol is renamed to `DeprecatedIn25` since version 2.5. But if you have version 2.4.2, you shouldn't have the problem anyway, according ot @Martin Prikryl. I would suggest saying `cryptography.utils.CryptographyDeprecationWarning`. That works in all versions. Thanks for the hint anyway.

Comment: Using cryptography.utils.CryptographyDeprecationWarning us certainly better. Thank you, Adrian.