# "type object 'EllipticCurvePublicKey' has no attribute 'from_encoded_point'" in pysftp/Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 droplets on DigitalOcean and need to set file transfers between them.

Pysftp/Paramiko libraries fits the job well, but I have trouble establishing connection. Connecting with same code from desktop works well.

```
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

with pysftp.Connection(host='ip adress',  username='username',
                       password='pass', cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
```

Error message when initializing connection is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/airflow/tasks/ta_auto/screener_slave.py", line 315, in <module>
    cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()#knownhosts='/home/airflow/.ssh/known_hosts')
  File "/home/airflow/pipeline/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 54, in __init__
    self.hostkeys.load(knownhosts)
  File "/home/airflow/pipeline/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/hostkeys.py", line 101, in load
    e = HostKeyEntry.from_line(line, lineno)
  File "/home/airflow/pipeline/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/hostkeys.py", line 364, in from_line
    key = ECDSAKey(data=decodebytes(key), validate_point=False)
  File "/home/airflow/pipeline/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/ecdsakey.py", line 163, in __init__
    key = ec.EllipticCurvePublicKey.from_encoded_point(
AttributeError: type object 'EllipticCurvePublicKey' has no attribute 'from_encoded_point'
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest version of Paramiko – 2.6 as of now.

This is most likely the same problem as in:
[How to silence EllipticCurvePublicNumbers.encode_point CryptographyDeprecationWarning when using Paramiko in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54861026/850848).

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not set `cnopts.hostkeys = None`, unless you do not care about security. For the correct solution see [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848)*.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out already. Problem was causing older version of Paramiko overriding new version in my enviroment. Manual hard delete of lib files solved the problem.