# CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-cryptography

I upgraded my system from python 2 to python 3, and now when I run my code:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
```

I am getting this error

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py:33:
CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.6 is no longer supported by the Python 
core team. Therefore, support for it is deprecated in cryptography and will be 
removed in a future release.
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: i upgraded my system from python 2 to python 3 now when i run my code i am getting this error

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py:33: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Therefore, support for it is deprecated in cryptography and will be removed in a future release. from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend 

please give suitable answer on it

Comment: All I see is a long error message. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question on Stackoverflow :)

Comment: i upgraded my system from python 2 to python 3 now when i run my code i am getting this error

CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team.
this is my question

Comment: What Python version are you running? If it's less than 3.6, you should upgrade to avoid this error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into this issue today and did some digging. Since the `os` is not provided I think you could consider one of the options below:

1. Upgrade your python version. This might be the best option since python [3.6 reached its EOL](https://endoflife.date/python).
2. You might be using SSH in your code. Consider installing an older version of [paramiko](https://pypi.org/project/paramiko/).
3. You can suppress the warning with these lines of code before importing Paramiko:

   ```
   import warnings 
   warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore',module='.*paramiko.*')
   ```

or If you want to be more selective about suppressing JUST that particular deprecation warning:

```
import warnings
from cryptography.utils import CryptographyDeprecationWarning
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=CryptographyDeprecationWarning)
```

[source for option 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51778764/obnoxious-cryptographydeprecationwarning-because-of-missing-hmac-compare-time-fu)

4. Check if you installed it using pip when you needed to use conda.

Answer (score 7):

on ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get upgrade docker-compose
```

docker-compose must be 2.X
after that you need to refer old command to new command so do this

```
alias docker-compose='docker compose'
```

Comment: How does this relate to the "CryptographyDeprecationWarning"?

Comment: i have solved my problem after that

Comment: The trick (per this answer) is to use `docker compose [up/down/logs/status]` instead of `docker-compose [up/down/logs/status]`. Drop the hyphen.

Comment: @mkst this is what worked for me after wasting a couple of hours trying everything

Answer (score 4):

One of the solutions here suggests using

```
from cryptography.utils import CryptographyDeprecationWarning
```

That didn't work in my case, since importing the warning object caused the warning itself as well.

Although it's not an elegant solution (since "elegant" would be to upgrade Python), the following worked for me instead:

```
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore',message='Python 3.6 is no longer supported')
```