# How to install pip on Python 2.7 in 2021

Tags: python-2.7, pip, ubuntu-14.04, pypi

I have legacy production servers that are still running Python 2.7.6.  We have a local environment built from the docker image for ubuntu 14.04 intended to replicate that environment (things still work there once everything is installed.)  The packer build script that creates this environment recently stopped working apparently due to PyPi dropping non-SNI support.

I tried using `get-pip.py` from the docs to download pip:

```
wget -c https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py
python2 get-pip.py
```

This gives me the following warning:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
/tmp/tmpBb3LJu/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:424: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Server Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
/tmp/tmpBb3LJu/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:164: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip<21.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip<21.0
```

The proposed solution for that is to use `pip` to upgrade `urllib3`
https://serverfault.com/questions/866062/easy-install-and-pip-fail-with-ssl-warnings

I don't have pip so I installed a legacy version using

```
apt-get install python-pip
```

This installs pip 1.5.4

When I try to `pip install "urllib3[secure]"` I get the following:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): urllib3[secure] in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  Installing extra requirements: 'secure'
Cleaning up...
```

If I try `pip install "urllib3[secure]" --upgrade` or `pip install --index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple/ --upgrade pip` I get:

```
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement urllib3[secure] in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Downloading/unpacking urllib3[secure]
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for urllib3[secure] in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

(the pip message reflects pip, not urllib3[secure])

When I try to use pip 1.5 to install uWSGI

```
pip install uWSGI
```

I get the following:

```
Downloading/unpacking uWSGI
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement uWSGI
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for uWSGI
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Upgrading pip doesn't work here either

```
Downloading/unpacking uWSGI==2.0.18 (from -r /root/requirements.txt (line 1))
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement uWSGI==2.0.18 (from -r /root/requirements.txt (line 1))
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for uWSGI==2.0.18 (from -r /root/requirements.txt (line 1))
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Reinstalling pip doesn't work:

```
python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
```

Gives me:

```
Downloading/unpacking pip
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pip
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

If I open `/root/.pip/pip.log` I see the following:

```
Downloading/unpacking pip
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: 403 Client Error: [[[!!! BREAKING CHANGE !!!]]] Support for clients that do not support Server Name Indication is temporarily disabled and will be permanently deprecated soon. See https://status.python.org/incidents/hzmjhqsdjqgb and https://github.com/pypa/pypi-support/issues/978 [[[!!! END BREAKING CHANGE !!!]]]
```

[The link](https://github.com/pypa/pypi-support/issues/978) says that SNI support was dropped:

```
For users of Python 2.7.{0...8}
Upgrading to the last Python 2.7 release is an option.

However, note that Python 2.7 series itself is now End of Life and support in pip was dropped with version 21.0.

For users of Python 2.6.x and lower:
Neither the Python core developers, or pip maintainers support Python 2.6 and below.

If someone is aware of a work around for this issue (SNI support specifically) they are welcome to share it here for others.

There is no recommended solution from the PyPI team.
```

How can I get a local environment set up for new developers to work on our legacy application?  I've created a new Python 3 dev server and local environment but it will be some time before I can roll out the staging and live environments, get everything moved over, and test it.

Comment: You need to upgrade Python to at least 2.7.9, better to 2.7.15+.

Comment: @phd I want the same version of python running on my local environment as the servers and I can't risk upgrading the servers as well because it's a different path to upgrade them.

Comment: With Python < 2.7.9 you can forget about PyPI. Perhaps the only way would be to use Python 2.7.15+ to download/build wheels in one container, copy the wheels to the container with old Python and install them [offline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758).

Comment: @phd I can't even get pip on the server to do that.

Comment: Install it manually from sources. 1st, install old Python2.7-compatible [`setuptools`](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/44.1.1/#files) from zip (`python setup.py install`), them install [`pip`](https://pypi.org/project/pip/20.3.4/#files) from .tar.gz the same way.

Comment: @phd I get this error when trying to install setuptools(with or without sudo):  
error: could not create 'build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7': Operation not permitted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234904/discussion-between-phd-and-jonathan-rys).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the message says, PyPi has [discontinued support](https://github.com/pypa/pypi-support/issues/978) for Python <2.7.9 as of May 6th 2021.  If you're running a version < 2.7.9 and you cannot upgrade to a newer version of Python then your only option is to manually download the wheels from [PyPi](https://pypi.org/).

These are the modification I needed to make to my build script to make it work:

I needed to install `software-properties-common` and `gcc`

```
apt-get install -y software-properties-common gcc
```

Then I downloaded (setuptools](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/44.1.1/#files) and unzipped and installed it:

```
python ./setuptools-44.1.1/setup.py install
```

Next, I downloaded [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/20.3.4/#files) and added it to a folder called `wheels`.  Then I could use the whl file to run pip to get pip

```
python ./wheels/pip-20.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip install --no-index --find-links ./wheels/ pip --ignore-installed
```

It was suggested to build a Docker container using Ubuntu 16.04 with Python 2.7.17 and use that to download the packages.

```
pip download -r requirements.txt
```

But the versions of the packages were wrong, so I ended up going through the requirements.txt and downloading each package manually from [PyPi](https://pypi.org/) and adding it to the `wheels` folder.  A running instance is useful so you can run `pip freeze` or look at a `requirements.txt` file to grab the version numbers of all the packages you need.

Now that I could use pip, I can install my other packages:

```
python pip install --no-index --find-links ./wheels/ -r /root/requirements.txt
```

This uncovered some dependencies that I hadn't downloaded packages for yet so I had to go through and download those and added them to the `wheels` folder.  There were a few other things I found needed different versions than I had originally downloaded and a few packages relied on [pbr](https://pypi.org/project/pbr/5.5.1/#files) and many more wanted [wheel](https://pypi.org/project/wheel/0.36.2/#files):

```
pip install --no-index --find-links ./wheels/ pbr==5.5.1 wheel==0.36.2
```

I also needed to download [cMake](https://pypi.org/project/cmake/3.20.5/#files) and add it to the `wheels` folder

After that I could install my `requirements.txt`:

```
pip install --no-index --find-links ./wheels/ -r /root/requirements.txt --ignore-installed
```

Answer (score 2):

May be late to the party but something similar happened to me while trying to make an HTTPS request with Python 2.7.6 (lack of SNI support). This was causing a lot of issues on a remote web server I work on.

Looking for answers I tried installing `urllib3[secure]` and entered a loophole since pip was complaining about a lack of SNI support to install this and other packages as well.

I found out this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54582701/6258641) which helped me install the required dependencies to make Python 2.7.6 and pip itself support SNI as well as install `urllib[secure]`.

You need to create a folder containing the required wheels (download them from PyPi using wget for instance):

> pip, asn1crypto, enum34, idna, six, ipaddress, pyOpenSSL, cffi,
> cryptography wheels; and also pycparser (a non-wheel, it will be a
> tar.gz)

Make sure the wheels you download support Python 2.7 and that you install pip before the rest of them.

In the original answer, its stated you can use `python -m OpenSSL.debug` to verify everything worked correctly (a ModuleNotFoundError would mean the pyOpenSSL package was not installed). You can also use `pip -V`to check that the new pip version was installed correctly as well.

After updating pip and installing these dependencies I was able to install urllib3[secure] and get SNI support from python as well as pip.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I am sharing this answer as an update to Jonathan Rys's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68403027/238074) that contains the steps required as of the date of this answer. I tried to keep this concise.

As the message says, PyPi has [discontinued support](https://github.com/pypa/pypi-support/issues/978) for Python <2.7.9 as of May 6th 2021.  If you're running a version < 2.7.9 and you cannot upgrade to a newer version of Python then your only option is to manually download the wheels from [PyPi](https://pypi.org/).

For Ubuntu 20.04, I have installed build-essential `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

I installed Python 2 from source, downloading [tar bundle](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/Python-2.7.18.tgz) and built and installed this. Note, I removed the python command, to avoid that old confusion, so we have python2 and python2.7 and also python3 (for example).

```
tar xf Python-2.7.18.tgz
cd Python-2.7.18
./configure && make && sudo make install
(cd /usr/local/bin;sudo rm python python-config)
cd ..
```

Now to get pip installed. Download [setuptools](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/44.1.1/#files) zip archive. Then install it:

```
unzip setuptools-44.1.1.zip
cd setuptools-44.1.1
python2 bootstrap.py
sudo python2 setup.py install
cd ..
```

Next, I downloaded [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/20.3.4/#files) .tar.gz archive. Then unpack and install it. Note, I took extra steps to preserve and restore the original python3 pip in /usr/local/bin. Pip for Python2 are still available as pip2 and pip2.7 in the same directory.

```
tar xf pip-20.3.4.tar.gz
cd pip-20.3.4
(cd /usr/local/bin;sudo mv pip pip-save)
sudo python2 setup.py install
(cd /usr/local/bin;sudo mv pip-save pip)
```

Now that I could use pip, I can install the most important package any Python user should install, ipython. Note that I do a user install for this and also preserve my "ipython" command to run python3 and have ipython2 to run python2:

```
pip2.7 install ipython
(cd ~/.local/bin;rm ipython;ln -s ipython3 ipython)
```

and it works!

```
$ ipython2
Python 2.7.18 (default, Jun 22 2022, 09:38:45)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.10.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
```