# how to downgrade pip version 10.0.0 to pip version 9.0.1?

Tags: python, pip

how to downgrade pip version 10.0.0 to pip version 9.0.1?

I upgraded my pip version to pip 10.0.0 but i can't seem to find most of the libraries from system interpreter. 
now i want to know how to downgrade from pip version 10.0.0
tried using command pip install pip=9.0.1 but had 'pip' is not recognized as internal or external command error

Comment: `pip install pip==9.0.1`

Comment: Downgrading pip will not have any effect on what libraries you already have installed.

Comment: it's not about the libraries that i have installed before, it;s about libraries that i can't install or find like pickle and tkinter

Comment: pickle and tkinter are built-in libraries, you don't need to install them, as they are also not on PyPi. There's no reason why anyone would want to install an older version of pip, but if you must, `py -m pip install pip==9.0.1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the reason for '...' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454769/what-is-the-reason-for-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-comman)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows

Answer (score 12):

Try this

```
sudo python -m pip install --force-reinstall pip==9.0.1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

pip install --upgrade pip==version

Answer (score 0):

Try following the accepted instruction below:
[Python pip3 - cannot import name 'main' error after upgrading pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836676/python-pip3-cannot-import-name-main-error-after-upgrading-pip)

I had the same issue after upgrading pip without thinking (for those interested in the issue. [This issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5240) in the pip repository explains it)