# Python -pip error after upgrading module

Tags: python-3.x, pip, location, egg

at first I need to mention that I already posted one question which was linked to this topic: [Error after upgrading pip: cannot import name 'main'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836676/error-after-upgrading-pip-cannot-import-name-main/51291715#51291715). Tried couple solutions from it but got myself in the corner not solving my problem at all. Then I asked question in linked topic, and got suggestion to make new question so here I am. I guess I misunderstood something so please help me.

When I try to install some package I get error:

```
bob@bob-Lenovo-G40-30:~$ sudo -H pip3 install instrumentino
Collecting instrumentino
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/14/1c69530f7171f5bfdcc115461e7212a4b4ba38fde52c2a9b70385f639b1c/instrumentino-1.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-6r0fuz4x/instrumentino/setup.py", line 2, in <module>
        import ez_setup
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ezup'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-6r0fuz4x/instrumentino/
```

also:

```
bob@bob-Lenovo-G40-30:~$ pip3 install ez_setup
Requirement already satisfied: ez_setup in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.9)
```

So i checked my PIP:`Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (10.0.1)`

Plus:

```
which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

and  it should be in:
`/bin/pip3`

I figured out that my upgraded pip3 is installed in wrong place.
it's in `/usr/local/bin/pip3` instead of `/bin/pip3`but from now on I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

1. `pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools --user`
   This should solve your issue with pip
   or
2. `python -m pip install --upgrade pip==9.0.3` [ This will downgrade the pip version ]

Check the pip version using `pip --version`