# In Windows 10, pip import error: cannot import name main after installing pipenv

Tags: python-2.7, pip, importerror, pipenv

I am trying to use pipenv as well as pip and having some issues. I installed pipenv using pip. I installed pipenv using pip. Then I went back and tried to run `pip -v` and got the following: `ImportError: cannot import name main.` I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836676/error-after-upgrading-pip-cannot-import-name-main) answered for Linux and Mac, but I cannot use `sudo` or `which` commands; I am on Windows 10 using the CMD console. In my scripts folder, I see pip, pip2.7, and pip2. I cannot remember which one was my system pip. I know I need to maybe uninstall and reinstall (I have already tried to upgrade, but of course, without pip running you can't upgrade pip). I don't want to make more of a mess, so I wanted to ask how to resolve this in the CMD console on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, when I installed pipenv, it changed the system pip version that I was previously using. For some reason, all of the answers I found were using Linux or Mac, but here is how I resolved it. Simply open your command prompt and type:

```
 $python -m pip uninstall pip
```

Then, test that you still have your old version installed by typing:

```
 $pip -V
```

This showed me that I had gone from using pip version 18 back to using version 8.1.1. You should then be able to proceed to other tasks using pip.