# Cannot upgrade pip

Tags: python, linux, pip, upgrade, openai-gym

I try to install openai-gym library, so I run this command: `pip install gym`
but I got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in
>   
>       from pip import main ImportError: cannot import name main

I searched and I got that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836676/error-after-upgrading-pip-cannot-import-name-main will help me, so I tried these commands: `sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python3-pip --reinstall`
but I got this error while running `sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip`:

> Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside
>   environment /usr You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 18.0
>   is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install
>   --upgrade pip' command.

And finally when I run `pip install --upgrade pip` again I got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in
>   
>       from pip import main ImportError: cannot import n

It becomes a loop and I don't know what to do?! :(

Comment: Try this https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: @Ashish I tried it and I got the message "Successfully installed pip-18.0", but when I run " sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip" I got previous message again. :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error after upgrading pip: cannot import name 'main'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836676/error-after-upgrading-pip-cannot-import-name-main)

Comment: @phd I saw that link before and I pointed to it in my question, but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @Ashish your link was usefull, thank you so much.