# Python3.6 ImportError: cannot import name 'main' after upgrading pip from 8.1.1 to 19.0.1

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

After I upgraded pip from 8.1.1 to 19.0.1 by running

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

I tried to test the version of pip by running

```
pip -V
```

But I got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

I set the python3 and pip3 to be default by putting the following in `~/.bashrc`

```
alias python=python3
alias pip=pip3
```

My system is ubuntu 16.04

Comment: This is a common issue as referenced here : https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5221 .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error after upgrading pip: cannot import name 'main'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836676/error-after-upgrading-pip-cannot-import-name-main)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common issue as referenced here : https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5221

You are trying to use the pip, which is shipped with the Debian system. You better try to avoid using that pip at any cost.

Please use `python3 -m pip install package` instead of the system pip which you have in the debian system.

I also recommend using [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) - virtual environments for keeping your system environment safe.