# Pip not working from file path or anywhere else

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to accomplish pip install formulas however keep getting this error

```
C:\Python27>python.exe c:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install formulas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "c:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

I have tried from path

`c:\python>python pip install formulas`

`c:\python>python c:\python\scripts\pip install formulas`

`c:\python\scripts> c:\python\python pip install formulas`

It doesnt matter what I try to pip install i continually get the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836676/error-after-upgrading-pip-cannot-import-name-main
Does this entry help you?

Comment: No, sorry that did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Install pip on your system**

> download get-pip.py

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

Open a command prompt and navigate to the folder containing get-pip.py.

Run the following command:

```
python get-pip.py
```

pip is now install !!

You can verify that Pip was installed correctly by opening a command prompt and entering the following command:

```
pip -V
```

**Or Upgrade PIP using:**

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem with this. Make sure pip is installed (python get-pip.py) and that you're in the python folder in the terminal (the version you're working with)