# Can’t run pip3 due to import error after upgrade

Tags: python-3.x, bash, pip, package, macos-high-sierra

I have macOS High Sierra and installed Python 3.6 a few days ago. Today I was installing a few packages using pip3, which worked great until I used:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip --user
```

Now when I use pip3 install for any package, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

I can’t figure out how to get pip3 working again. I don’t have permissions to use sudo. What can I check for? Is there a way to undo whatever that command did?

**EDIT**
The following line fixed pip for me:

```
python3 -m pip install --user pip==9.0.1
```

Comment: @Ruturaj per my post I can’t use sudo, so I’m looking for another solution

Comment: I know, there are solutions without sudo, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836676/error-after-upgrading-pip-cannot-import-name-main#answer-50492636). Please try those first.

Comment: @Ruturaj, Claire’s solution fixed it for me. Thanks! "python3 -m pip install --user pip==9.0.1"