# What is the proper way to decide whether to allow unsafe package versions in pip-tools?

Tags: python, pip, pip-tools

I am trying to use pip-tools to manage a venv (as in `python -m venv .venv`) environment. The freshly-activated environment has nothing but pip-tools initially:

```
> pip list
Package   Version
--------- -------
Click     7.0
pip       19.3.1
pip-tools 4.2.0
six       1.13.0
```

I created a `requirements/main.in` file with just:

```
numpy
matplotlib
```

Running `pip-compile --upgrade --build-isolation --generate-hashes --output-file requirements/main.txt requirements/main.in` gives me this warning:

```
# WARNING: The following packages were not pinned, but pip requires them to be
# pinned when the requirements file includes hashes. Consider using the --allow-unsafe flag.
# setuptools==41.6.0        # via kiwisolver
The generated requirements file may be rejected by pip install. See # WARNING lines for details.
```

As warned, `pip install --upgrade -r requirements/main.txt` rejects the operation with:

```
ERROR: In --require-hashes mode, all requirements must have their versions pinned with ==. These do not:
    setuptools from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d9/de/554b6310ac87c5b921bc45634b07b11394fe63bc4cb5176f5240addf18ab/setuptools-41.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=3e8e8505e563631e7cb110d9ad82d135ee866b8146d5efe06e42be07a72db20a (from kiwisolver==1.1.0->-r requirements/main.txt (line 11))
```

So now my predicament is: should I use `--allow-unsafe`? What are the implications of doing this? I tried it and found that the generated requirements file has it pinned to that particular version, which `kiwisolver` (I guess a transitive dependency of numpy/matplotlib) needs right? But why is this unsafe?

If I understand it correctly, I can keep my generated requirements for as long as I want, but then - whenever I decide to update - I can re-run pip-compile and create a new requirements file will be fresh and it may have a new kiwisolver that does not have this restriction, right?

What is the reason pip-tools is asking ME to make this decision? Why is this potentially unsafe and what examples are there where one would NOT want to use --allow-unsafe?

A related question is: can I specify to "--allow-unsafe" ONLY for setuptools? It seems to be a parameter of pip-compile which is an all-or-nothing approach. Can I just flag the particular one as "ok to pin"? I would like to be warned again if some OTHER case arises so I can assess whether that's ok or not?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> So now my predicament is: should I use `--allow-unsafe`?  What are the implications of doing this?

Yes, you should. This option allows you to pin in `requirements.txt` the following packages: `distribute`, `pip`, and `setuptools`. If you don't care, go ahead!

> But why is this unsafe?

AFAIK, those packages could be considered unsafe for the following reasons:

- Changing the `setuptools` may cause conflicts with `pip` (
  `distribute` is the legacy wrapper of `setuptools`, and it's
  deprecated since 2013).
- Changing `pip` could break `pip-tools` itself or [your system `pip`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836676/error-after-upgrading-pip-cannot-import-name-main/49836753#49836753).

That said, discussions in [pip-tools'](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools/issues/806#issuecomment-493591664) and [pip's](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6459) issue-trackers imply that `--allow-unsafe` is considered safe enough that
it may become the default option in future.

Comment: Thanks for including the link to those issue trackers. This seems to be like a "theoretically correct bootstrapping concern" which in practice everyone will want to ignore and just allow the "unsafe" behavior.

Comment: I'm inclined to think this flag is there for historical reasons, which may be not relevant nowadays.