# When ever I try to import any open source library or try to upgrade my pip this error pops up. Can someone please help me?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.9

This is the error

ImportError: cannot import name 'raise_for_status' from 'pip._internal.network.utils' (c:\users\aditya\appdata\local\pro
grams\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\network\utils.py)

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49836676/10895906) and especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49836753/10895906)

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading **pip** or adding **--no-cache-dir** to the command might help.

Comment: actually, Python was not added to the system path. My bad.