# System PIP seems broken after I tried to upgrade it on my Big Sur / Apple silicon Macbook

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

It seems like I messed up the system pip by `pip3 install --upgrade pip`. Actually I even do not exactly remember whether I did upgrade or not.

Now when I try to use `pip3`, it gives an error like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/pip3", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'pip._internal' (unknown location)
```

I tried `sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python3-pip --reinstall` to revert back PIP by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49836753/6642768), but it fails.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip.__main__; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

`which pip3` gives `/usr/bin/pip3`

Now I am trying to revert back the system tools and use virtual environment.
What should I do? I can't even check which pip version is installed at the moment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not exactly an answer, more like a last resort -- I'd try to install homebrew and install pip via homebrew.

Comment: Have you tried [get-pip.py](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py)

Comment: @AmosBaker Now I am using the virtual environment in my projects but the system's pip might still be in problem. Is it what completely reinstalls the system's pip?